# Using argument in title

Tags: 8, views

I am using a contextual filter for a view in Drupal 8. The contextual filter is a Taxonomy Term: name filter with a term relationship. It works correctly.

I'm now trying to override the title using this filter. In previous versions of Drupal, using %1 would have given me the argument. But not in Drupal 8. Is there a way to either get the argument or (even better) the term name into the title override?

Answer (score 4):

> or (even better) the term name into the title override?

1) Add `Taxonomy term: Name` as a field

- Check `Exclude from display`
- Uncheck `Link this field to its taxonomy term page`

2) Click on *Title:* and put `{{ name }}`

Comment: I can tell you are new here, you can accept my answer by clicking the ✅ checkmark, thx.

Comment: Hi @No Sssweat, what if I'm using Teaser view mode, and not field. I already set using override title using `{{ arguments.name }}`, but it doesn't seem to work.