# How to use a contextual filter argument (term ID) in a View page title?

Tags: 8, views

[This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224940/using-argument-in-title) asks how to use a Views contextual filter argument as the title when using a **Taxonomy Term: Name** filter.

My question is how to set the name of a view page to a contextual filter argument when using a **Content: Has taxonomy term ID** filter.

My View looks like this.

Show **Taxonomy terms** of type **Group** (my custom vocabulary)

Type: Page

Path: `/groups/%`

Contextual filter:

- `(field_ref_term_group) Content: Has taxonomy term ID`
- When the filter value is NOT in the URL: Show "Page not found"
- When the filter value IS in the URL: Specify validation criteria (Taxonomy term ID)

Relationships: `Relate each Content with a field_ref_term_group set to the taxonomy term.`, required

Fields: **Taxonomy term: Name** [hiddden], `Link to the Taxonomy term` is unchecked

View settings screenshot:

[image: view settings screenshot]

I then set the View title to `{{ name }}`. After saving and clearing the cache and navigating to the view path (`/groups/4`), then I see the page title (the `<title>` tag) as `{{ name }}` instead of the name of term 4.

How can I print the actual term name as the View title when using a **Content: Has taxonomy term ID** relationship?

Comment: Did you add it as a hidden (exclude from display) field?

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes, it's hidden.  I unhid it to check that the output was OK, and then I hid it again.

Comment: Works as expected for me using Article content type & tags and [same setup](https://i.imgur.com/Oe6x6qk.png). Are you using latest D8 version? Is this a **[group](https://www.dell.com/support/contents/en-ca/article/esupport-order-support/order-change-returns)** view?

Comment: Hmm. I am using the latest 8.9.4. I rebuilt the view using the simplest possible configuration to reproduce the error.  The view is of taxonomy terms; the content is pulled in via a relationship.

Comment: On fresh D8 install, I just did one [using Taxonomy terms view](https://i.imgur.com/ftxXOoZ.png) and it's still works as expected. Was not able to replicate the issue. Even when there is no result for title (using term ID of other vocab), it shows empty and it's not printing {{ name }}. Try switching your theme to Bartik and see if that makes any difference.